# How can I use an exsisting column as sample ID

Tags: r, r-rownames

I imported an excel file with animal data that looks something like this:

| AnimalID | Sex | Body Weight | District |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB1 | 1 | 3.45 | 4 |
| AB2 | 1 | 2.98 | 4 |
| AB3 | 2 | 3.22 | 5 |
| AB4 | 2 | 3.01 | 5 |

I want to use to use my first column(AnimaID) as rownames.

I've searched for an answer but most questions address the creation of a new column that then becomes the rownames column. I actually feel stupid coming on here and asking this. My aim is to create a pca plot using ggplot2, and that requires me to have the dataframe in the format that ggplots2 recognizes.

Comment: `row.names(df1) <- df1[["AnimaID"]]; df1 <- df1[-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
rownames(df) <- df$AnimalID
df <- df[,-1]
df

#>     Sex Body.Weight District
#> AB1   1        3.45        4
#> AB2   1        2.98        4
#> AB3   2        3.22        5
#> AB4   2        3.01        5
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% column_to_rownames("AnimalID")

#>     Sex Body.Weight District
#> AB1   1        3.45        4
#> AB2   1        2.98        4
#> AB3   2        3.22        5
#> AB4   2        3.01        5
```

Comment: The first solution worked. I'm gonna bookmark this for future reference. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Another `base` option:

```
row.names(df) <- df$AnimalID
df[1] <- NULL
```

Output:

```
    Sex Body_Weight District
AB1   1        3.45        4
AB2   1        2.98        4
AB3   2        3.22        5
AB4   2        3.01        6
```

Comment: Just tried it. It worked thank you.